# eclipse.ini -vm has conflict with environment variables

Tags: java, eclipse

I have eclipse can't start correctly, i have tried two ways:

1. set environment variables about java, and running and compiling in windows cmd is fine. i have no admin rights and system path have wrong java path but i can't change it. so the eclipse will crash.
2. use -vm option in eclipse.ini without java_home setting, have following error:

   `java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry.`

my eclipse.ini:

```
`-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\software\java\jdk_1.7.0_89\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
`
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Eclipse Neon and Oxygen require Java 8.

Comment: eclipse neon4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse Neon (and Eclipse Oxygen) both require Java 8 to run, you appear to be running Java 7. You will have to install Java 8 and specify its location in the eclipse.ini.